# Array of Arrays 2D max value

Tags: java, arrays

I am having difficulty in making the logic for my scenario which i m considering an array of arrays more specifically said as 2D array.i want to find the maximum value in 2D arrays i do not want to call it in main method.i am making the array as annonymous and calling the function of max from it via static data members.the code is as follows.do let me know the logic to find the greatest no in 2D array as i m finding it difficult to which value to compare with the array.the code is as follows:-

```
class Max2DArray
{
    static int i;
    static int j;
    static int large;//largest number

    int max(int x[][])
    {
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<x[i].length;i++)
            {
                if(x[i][j]<=???)//what should be the comparison here.
                {
                    ??//what should be done here??
                }
            }
        }
        return large
    }
    public static void main(String... s)
    {
        Max2DArray m1 = new Max2DArray();
        int t = m1.max(new int[][]{{20,10,5},
                                   {5,7,6},
                                    {23,31,16}});
        System.out.println("the largest number is = "+t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should make use of the variable named `large`? (BTW, `large` probably shouldn't be `static` and `i` and `j` shouldn't be fields.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int max(int x[][]){
    // Initialize the value to the lowest value
    int large = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
            // Check if the current value is greater than large
            if(x[i][j] > large) {
               // It is greater so we keep the new value
               large = x[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return large;
}
```

Using java 8, it could simply be:

```
int max(int x[][]){
    return Arrays.stream(x).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).max().getAsInt();
}
```

Comment: Not allowed a one-character edit; but `return large` should have a semi-colon.  This returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE` for an empty 2d-array.  Not sure what the appropriate response is for that (IllegalArgumentException?) but worth considering.  Otherwise, exactly what I was gonna say :).

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to solve it to you but here is an algorithm

1. Have a local variable max
2. assign max to the first value of the array
3. iterate through the array and change the value of max whenever you find a value greater that the current value of max.
4. return max

Answer (score 0):

A Java 8 one-liner, instead of your for loop:

```
Arrays.stream(x).flatMapToInt(arr2 -> Arrays.stream(arr2)).max().getAsInt();
```